# Module not found Error: Can't resolve 'http' in a reactapp using authorize.net

Tags: node.js, reactjs, magento2, authorize.net

I am trying to run `npm run build` on a react app which uses the `charge-credit-card.js` from Authorize.net `node.js` SDK inside a react app (Hyva React Checkout) like so:

`import { chargeCreditCard } from '../api/charge-credit-card';`

However I am getting this kind of error in the console while running `npm run build` on the react app:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/var/www/html/app/code/MyVendorName/Checkout/reactapp/node_modules/authorizenet/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports'
Did you mean './http'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, /var/www/html/app/code/MyVendorName/Checkout/reactapp/node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
        - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
```

Not entirely sure why this is happening and how it can be mitigated.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: A react app typically runs in the browser, so you can't use node stuff. Sometimes there are possible polyfills you can use as replacement, but I would assume that the SDK is meant to run on the backend, not frontend.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @super. Yes that makes sense. It was written to be used in a back-end setup. I am indeed trying to run it from the react-app.

In this case, what could be my options in this situation in order to make it work?

Before making this post, I wanted to pass some order details such as name, address, items, amount, base url, country to the node.js app etc. such that order can be placed.

Comment: Typically you make a backend that your react-app can talk to. If this has to do with payments and need some form of security I would definately not trust a client to handle that stuff. You need a backend in between to validate what the client is doing.